# Count of numbers where both $n$ and $n+1$ have all prime factors less than $x$

Tags: number-theory

If there are $m$ primes less than $x$ then I believe that there are at most $O(\log^m N)$ numbers less than $N$ all of whose prime factors are less than $x$.  This should mean that the number of numbers where both $n$ and $n+1$ have all their prime factors less than $x$ is finite if we consider the tests for $n$ and $n+1$ to be independent random events, and that is optimistic as $n$ and $n+1$ cannot share a prime factor.   I'd like to know, as a function of $m$ and the primes less than $x$ how many such numbers we "expect" to find in all of the natural numbers.

This came up while playing with this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11398/the-order-of-the-number-of-integer-pairs-satisfying-certain-arithmetical-function/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the discussion of Stormer's Theorem at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormer's_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormer%27s_theorem) and elsewhere.

Comment: More than I could have wished for.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gerry:  +1, You beat me to it!  I was 6 minutes too late!

Comment: I knew that, some day, my investment in ultra-fast electrons would pay off....

Answer (score 7):

Your question is answered near the bottom.  However, I think you will find the first part interesting as it is related.

**The function $\psi(x,y)$**

We let $\psi(x,y)$ denote the number of positive integers $\leq x$ such that all of their prime factors are $\leq y$.  Something important is that we can understand $\psi(x,y)$ very well when $y$ is fixed and $x$ grows very large, and also when $y$ grows like some fractional power of $x$.

Above you claim that $\psi(x,y)\ll \log^{\pi(y)}(x)=\exp\left(\pi(y)\log \log x\right)$.  While this is true, for large $y$ it is not very good and we can actually do much better.  Assume that $x=y^u$.  Then we have $$\psi(x,y)=x\rho(u)+O\left(\frac{x\log(u+1)}{\log y}\right)$$ where the error term is uniform for $$1\leq u\leq \exp\left (\log y)^{\frac{3}{5}-\epsilon}\right).$$  Here $\rho(u)$ refers to the [Dickman De-Bruijn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function) rho function. For a complete survey of results regarding $\psi(x,y)$ see Hildebrand and Tenenbaum's 1993 paper "Integers Without Large Prime Factors."  It is also worth noting that uniformety in a larger range is equivalent to improving the error term in the prime number theorem.  This is proven in Hildebrand 1982.

**The number of $n$ and $n+1$ which are both smooth:**  For $y$ fixed, this problem is very well known, and is exactly the statement of [Stormers Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem).  This theorem says that given $y$ fixed, there are only finitely many pairs of integers $n,n+1$ where both have prime factors smaller then $y$.  In fact, Stormer gave a method of finding all such pairs based on [Pell equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_equation).

I am not sure what happens if we allow $y$ to go to infinity with $x$.  I tried to work it out without success, but I think it is an interesting question to ask.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you.  I knew that my estimate was not good, it was enough to convince myself that there were probably only finitely many consecutive pairs.  I never expected an effective algorithm to find pairs.